# PowerShell: Load Assembly via []?

Tags: powershell

In this [articles](https://sites.utexas.edu/glenmark/2019/10/21/using-passwordvault-with-powershell/) the author states:

> The first step is to load the Credentials and PasswordVault assemblies:

```
[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
```

I always thought loading is done via `Add-Type`. Can someone explain me above syntax, or post a docu link were it is explained (I was not able to found something about that).

Comment: Implicit type loading via fully qualified type literals (like your example) only works for WinRT types, and this behavior is unfortunately terribly un(der)documented.